# Sorting a list of tuples (Python 3.5)

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples, python-3.5

What's the best way to sort a list of tuples of `(x, y)`'s. I want to sort in terms of `x`'s but when there are `x`'s of the same values, I want to break and sort in terms of `y`.

Answer (score 1):

For a given list of two element tuples sharing the first `x` value and differing in `y` values:

```
t = [(1, 2), (1, 1), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 6)]
```

You can sort based on your criteria simply by `sorted` (or `sort`) since `tuples` (inside the list) considers all elements while sorting:

```
>>> sorted(t)  
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 6)]
```

That is, conflicts at the first matching value are resolved by examining the next value in the sequence until one of the values is smaller than the other (i.e [*lexicographical sorting*](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types)).

If no value is found to resolve the conflict, Python is going to retain the ordering as is found in the input sequence. This is another characteristic of sorting called [*stability*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability).

Comment: This works because sequences (which includes tuples) are compared *lexicographically*, i.e., the first items are compared, then the second items if those are equal, etc. [Docs here.](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types)

Comment: Also, if you already have the tuples in a list and don't mind modifying it, `list.sort()` will be a bit more efficient as it doesn't have to allocate/copy them to a new list first (`sorted` will).

Comment: @BenHoyt yes and yes, `sorted` returning the list means it is outputted in the interactive interpreter w/o a need to explicitly `print` or `repr` it by pressing `<enter>`  thereby translating to less copying and pasting. :-)